# Afrontar un problema de diseño

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una práctica para la universidad y necesito un poco de ayuda de cara a afrontar un problema.
Para poneros en situación, tenemos que realizar una práctica en la que tenemos que desarrollar un sistema integrado de gestión de bibliotecas.

En un punto de la práctica nos piden realizar una búsqueda flexible sobre los elementos del inventario de la biblioteca. En este inventario se encuentran cinco tipos diferentes de objetos (Libro, Revista, Periódico, Audio y Video) todas ellas tienen sus propios campos más otros heredados de la clase padre Material.

Ahora, la interacción tiene que ser mediante consola por lo que tendría que :

1 - Preguntar al usuario qué objeto quiere buscar ( Ej : Libro, Revista... )

2 - En función del objeto que haya introducido mostrar un menú dentro de un bucle while con cada uno de los campos de esa clase para que elija por cuáles quiere filtrar.

3 - Realizar un switch en el cual recoja cada elección y recopile el valor que quiere introducir a cada campo.

4 - Llamar finalmente a un método de búsqueda el cual me diga si existe o no ese material en función de los campos que haya introducido ( este método ya lo tengo implementado )

5 - Repetir los tres primeros pasos cinco veces, un menú por material y un switch por cada menú

Mi pregunta es :  ¿existe alguna forma de hacer esto dinámicamente y de manera eficaz, evitándome tener que crear cinco switchs y cinco menús diferentes para cada tipo de material?

He pensado en usar Reflection de manera que puedo generar dinámicamente el menú con el método getDeclaredFields + obtener los campos de la super clase y recorriendo ese array, pero después de leer sobre Reflection y su eficacia y velocidad igual es mejor opción incluso crear los cinco menús con cinco switchs.

También he pensado en implementar mi propio Switch, siguiendo algunos ejemplos de Internet, de forma que sea dinámico y se adapte al número de items que tenga el menú ( Ya que cada menú de cada tipo de material tendrá más o menos campos por lo que más o menos opciones )

Espero haberme explicado , no pongo código porque es un problema más de concepto.
La pregunta es : **¿Alguien puede iluminarme con una forma óptima en la que a la vez que me ahorro duplicar código gane eficacia?**

**Edit : No creo que me refiera a una opinión de cada persona. Estoy pidiendo posibles soluciones, por lo que cada opción dada, mientras cumpla los requisitos, será una solución, no una opinión. Un saludo**

Comment: ¿Tienes que utilizar todos los campos de la clase para realizar la búsqueda o pueden ser menos? Sería bueno si colocaras un ejemplo. Se me ocurren algunos patrones de diseño y quizás acompañado de reflection para resolver tu dilema pero quisiera conocer más antes de lanzar mis ideas.

Comment: Esta pregunta no debería cerrarse de acuerdo a lo conversado en meta: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227), específicamente en [esta respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/163/227).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hola Luiggi, no estoy obligado a usar todos los campos. Para que te hagas una idea yo mostraría un menú con todos los campos de esa clase y el usuario elegiría cuáles usar y cuáles no. Por ejemplo : ¿Qué deseas buscar? Introduzco "libro" y acto seguido muestro todos los campos de la clase Libro en forma de menú para que elija. Si tienes cualquier otra duda o necesitas un ejemplo en forma de imagen, házmelo saber

Comment: Mira este pequeño ejemplo que hice: https://github.com/migamipe/SearchItemsConsole. Como dice Luiggi se podría utilizar uno que otro patrón para solventar este problema.

Comment: Gracias @MitsuGami estoy echándole un ojo

Comment: @MitsuGami corrígeme si me equivoco ya que he tenido que leer de manera algo rápida tu código pero según veo, cuando le pides un criterio de búsqueda, le pides un valor de un campo y lo comparas con todos los campos que sean String. Por ejemplo yo te doy "Los puentes de Madison" y tu me comparas esa String con todos los campos String definidos en la clase Libro. Correcto?

Comment: Así es, por eso hago una distinción si es String para usar `contains`.

Comment: El caso es que yo necesito consultar por varios campos simultaneamente, no solo por un campo. Ahí viene mi principal problema

Comment: @MitsuGami cualquier intento de respuesta a una pregunta debe realizarse por el sitio. Asimismo, el código propuesto debe estar escrito en el sitio. Usualmente, no se debería brindar código particular para responder la pregunta fuera del sitio, no va muy acorde a los estándares del sitio.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Obviamente, el asunto es que como está on hold no puedo responderle al OP.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza te quedó claro con el ejemplo que te puse?

Comment: @JoseMariaGarcia sí entendí. Mi duda ahora es sobre cómo piensas realizar la búsqueda. Al parecer tienes los datos en memoria, imagino que arreglos, por ende si tus formas de búsqueda también dependerían de este `switch` que mencionas pero al parecer quieras evitar, no sé si en primer lugar conviene mantener todo almacenado en clases o si sería mejor trabajar con otro tipo de estructuras de datos.

Comment: Los datos los tengo en memoria , sí, concretamente en HashSets. Tengo un HashSet por cada clase ( Libro, Revista etc..) aunque hereden del mismo padre y pudiendo haber creado un HashSet de la clase padre Material donde meta todos juntos, un requisito de la práctica es que todos tengan su propia colección.

Mi método de búsqueda ya está implementado y funciona. Respecto al switch, es verdad que me gustaría evitarlo, porque como puedes ver, necesitaría cinco switchs diferentes, uno por menú de cada clase ( libro, revista...) .

Comment: Entonces en cuanto a eficiencia, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de evitar eso. Algo así como lo que dijiste desplegando los menús de forma dinámica con Reflection, para evitar crear cinco menús diferentes a mano.

Comment: Para evitarte el `switch` de decidir sobre qué vas a mostrar al usuario, puedes usar un *truco* bien simple: Declara un `Map<Integer, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<>();` y llénalo de esta manera: `map.put(1, Libro.class); map.put(2, Revista.class); ...` de manera que cuando el usuario seleccione 1 para realizar la búsqueda de `Libro` vayas a `map` y obtengas (vía reflection) los campos de la clase y los muestres, y reutilizas dicho método para las otras clases.

Comment: Entiendo, pero una vez los muestre, el switch que me gestione esos campos, cuales elige y cuales no para filtrar la búsqueda va a tener que ser particular para cada elección verdad? Porque si nuestro los campos por reflection igual la clase Libro tiene 5 y la clase Revista 6. Por lo que tendrían que ser dos switch diferentes verdad? Y por lo tanto cinco diferentes. Uno por clase

Comment: Si trabajas con `Map`, es irrelevante el número de `switch`s que vayas a utilizar, todo se vuelve más genérico. Y por favor, para responder a alguien en comentario utiliza `@nombre` porque sino no recibo una notificación de que me hayas respondido.

Answer (score 0):

La forma óptima que evita duplicar código y a la vez ganar eficiencia No Existe.

Siempre tienes que balancear ambos y priorizar el que sea más importante en cada caso.

Esta al ser una aplicación en consola, el código que obtiene por reflection los campos me parece una solución bastante buena ya que evita escribir bastante código repetitivo y posiblemente frágil si se cambia la estructura de las clases a la vez que el impacto en rendimiento es irrelevante.

Es verdad que usar reflection tiene un rendimiento menor que un código estático sin embargo en este caso el código corre en el cliente, es decir la aplicacion en consola, por lo que hay un único usuario usándola a la vez en un mismo proceso/maquina. El usuario final no notará la diferencia para nada.

Comment: Vale Carlos, tomo nota. Aún así, usar Reflection si me podría generar los menús dinámicamente. Pero seguiría teniendo el problema de tener un switch por cada menú, ya que cada menú tendría diferente número de opciones (campos). Alguna idea para evitar eso? He leído sobre switchs dinámicos pero igual no tengo nivel suficiente para llevarlo a cabo. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: No se que tan compleja pueda llegar a ser tu aplicación pero hay algo que debes tener en cuenta. Una CLI (Command Line Interface) es una UI es decir interfaz de usuario y debe ser tratada como tal a pesar de no ser gráfica. Puedes tratar de separar la interfaz de usuario de la lógica del negocio, y así tener una clase que represente la jerarquía de menus que deseas mostrar. Luego crear el árbol de menús a partir de tus clases de dominio/negocio y tener lógica que trate directamente con tus opciones sin importar que contengan. Es dificl de explicar sin código de lo que tienes actualmente

Comment: Me encantaría pasarte código Carlos pero creo que solo te confundiría más ya que es bastante cantidad.

Te intento explicar un poco, la lógica la tengo separada de la parte de interfaz de usuario, la cual tengo toda ahora mismo en el Main ( aunque tarde o temprano la gestionaré y dividiré en métodos ).

Lo que te comento es que, aunque genere dinámicamente esos menús   mediante Reflection siempre voy a tener que realizar un Switch por cada menú generado de cada clase en el cual el usuario eligirá por qué campos desea filtrar. Me sigues?